# Retreive last order of each customer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating an API for the shop. There I should return the last order of each customer.
Here is the code for my Customer and Order models.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=14, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True)
    address = models.TextField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Order(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is serializers.py

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'country', 'address', 'phone']

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = CustomerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id', 'date', 'customer']
```

I am getting the last order of each customer using Django ORM in the following way

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def customers_last_orders(request):
    orders = models.Order.objects.all().order_by('customer', '-date').distinct()
    serializer = serializers.OrderSerializer(orders, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

But I am getting from this view all the orders in descinding order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [the OuterRef](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) for annotating using a subquery.

```py
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
from django.http import JsonResponse

@api_view(('GET',))
def customers_last_orders(request):
    latest = Order.objects.filter(customer=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-date')
    customer_latest_order = Customer.objects.annotate(latest_order=Subquery(latest.values('id', 'date')[:1])).values()

    return JsonResponse(list(customer_latest_order), safe=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You order by `customer`, then `-date`, so it applies for order by `customer` first.
Your queryset should be:

```
orders = models.Order.objects.all().order_by('-date').distinct()
```

The data will return the **orders**, not **customers**.

---

But if you want to get the customer list have the latest order objects, it should be:

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id', 'date']

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orders = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'country', 'address', 'phone', 'orders',]

        def get_orders(self, instance):
            """
            Custom to order Order items
            """

            orders = instance.orders.order_by('-date') 
            # Update to `orders = instance.orders.order_by('-date')[:1]` if you just need only one latest order item.
            return OrderSerializer(orders, many=True).data
```

**viewsets.py**

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def customers_last_orders(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.all().order_by('...')
    serializer = serializers.CustomerSerializer(customers, many=True)

    # Order by customer's orders
    data = sorted(serializer.data, key=lambda item: item['orders'][0]['date'], reverse=True)
    return Response(data)
```

Not tested yet, but it should works. I am worrying a bit about `sorted(...)` ^^

Comment: I checked the first version of your solution but it did not work. The second version is too long so I didn't try.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test but maybe it will work objects.all()[:1]

```
orders = models.Order.objects.all()[:1].order_by('customer', '-date').distinct()
```

or use .reverse()[:1]

```
orders = models.Order.objects.all().order_by('customer', '-date').reverse()[:1]
```

because

> "Any fields used in an order_by() call are included in the SQL SELECT
> columns. This can sometimes lead to unexpected results when used in
> conjunction with distinct(). If you order by fields from a related
> model, those fields will be added to the selected columns and they may
> make otherwise duplicate rows appear to be distinct. Since the extra
> columns don’t appear in the returned results (they are only there to
> support ordering), it sometimes looks like non-distinct results are
> being returned." [QuerySet.distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)